# Error on adding self signed certificate in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I used several links like(http://billcomer.blogspot.in/2010/03/ssl-tomcat-and-self-signed-certificates.html) to generate `ssl` certificate for my local `Tomcat`.

But every time I see `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` in the browser. I have already gone through other answers but they don't help. Connector tag for the same :

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" kestoreFile="/home/run/ssl/tomcat.ks" keystorePass="changeit"/>
```

Comment: The link you provided is drivel. He says himelf he doesn't understand it. See for example step 1.4 where the `cp` command is attributed with the magical powers of removing a passphrase. And creating your own CA is completely pointless unless its certificate is imported into client browsers, which is no easier than importing a self-signed certificate. And none of it constitutes using a self-signed certificate. Don't rely on arbitrary Internet junk.Try using the official Tomcat documentation. The simplest solution to all this is to use a CA-signed certificate. Pay the money and save more.